# How do I coalesce a Time field in Teradata?

Tags: time, teradata, coalesce

I'm trying to run the following piece of code:

```
SELECT a.job_name
     , coalesce(b.target_time, cast('08:00:00' as time(2))) sla_time

FROM ud812.slarpt_job_level_info a
left outer join ( 
   select job_name, target_time
   from ud812.slarpt_job_target_times 
   qualify row_number() over (partition by job_name 
                              order by established_date desc) = 1
   ) b
on (a.job_name = b.job_name)
where  a.display_on_sla_report = 'Y' 
   and a.job_type = 'LD'
   and a.decom_date is null
```

In doing so, I get the error "Select Failed 3800:  Datatype Mismatch in THEN/ELSE expression.
This relates to my use of coalesce.

When I check my data types:  select type(target_time) from ud812.slarpt_job_target_times qualify...  I get time(2).
I have tried several things to adjust my code.

These include:  Using a different data types ex. time(6).
I have even tried the following, but the type for sla_time comes back as integer.

```
SELECT a.job_name
      , cast(coalesce(b.target_time, '08:00:00') as time(2)) sla_time

FROM ud812.slarpt_job_level_info a
left outer join ( 
   select job_name, cast(target_time as char(8)) as target_time
   from ud812.slarpt_job_target_times 
   qualify row_number() over (partition by job_name 
                              order by established_date desc) = 1
   ) b
on (a.job_name = b.job_name)
where  a.display_on_sla_report = 'Y' 
   and a.job_type = 'LD'
   and a.decom_date is null
```

In the end, I"m trying to establish a default time with each job name of 8 am.
Ideas?

I have also tried the following , but when I type() the column it returns an integer, not time(2).

```
SELECT a.job_name
     , cast(coalesce(b.target_time, default_time) as time(2)) sla_time
FROM ( 
   select job_name, '08:00:00' as default_time
   from ud812.slarpt_job_level_info
   where  a.display_on_sla_report = 'Y' 
     and a.job_type = 'LD'
     and a.decom_date is null
   ) a
left outer join ( 
   select job_name, target_time
   from ud812.slarpt_job_target_times 
   qualify row_number() over (partition by job_name 
                              order by established_date desc) = 1
   ) b
on (a.job_name = b.job_name)
```

Comment: Target database is Teradata 13.x

Comment: What is the exact data type for the column `target_time` in the table `ud812.slarpt_job_target_times`?  From SQL Assistant, do `show select * from ud812.slarpt_job_target_times` to see the definition.

Comment: TARGET_TIME TIME(2) NOT NULL,

Comment: How are you running this query (SQL Assistant, BTEQ)?  The first example works as expected for me...

Answer (score 0):

In the test case below the `COALESCE()` works when you use the format `TIME '00:00:01'` as the replacement value for NULL.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE MyTable, NO FALLBACK
( MyID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  MyTime TIME(2)
)
PRIMARY INDEX (MyID) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (1, TIME '01:23:45');
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (2, NULL);

SELECT *
FROM MyTable;

SELECT MyID
     , COALESCE(MyTime, TIME '23:45:01')
 FROM MyTable;
```